# How to open editor outside of qlistview?

Tags: qt, qlistview, qstyleditemdelegate

The QAbstractItemView::openPersistentEditor method calls the createEditor method reimplemented in a class inherited from the QStyledItemDelegate class. It opens a widget inside the current item. But my task is to show the editor widget in some custom way. Say, under the current item, but with it's right border outside of the scroll area of the view. And it's height being far more, than just one item's height. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It opens a widget inside the current item because the current item its parent.
One of the solutions is the following: you provide a simple editor widget which is shown inside the current item, which really does not provide editing, only data exchange.

But this editor widget creates custom widget as a dialog or as a widget whose parent is the topmost ItemView. Or you can delegate the creation of the custom editor widget to the ItemView. The result of the editing is sent to the in-item editor widget which does the job of providing the ItemView with newly edited data.